# Hot Code Replace Failed in Eclipse - Delete method not implemented

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, embedded-tomcat-7, tomcat7-maven-plugin

I'm developing a java web-application with vaadin and spring and I'm using tomcat7-maven-plugin like application server during development. The problem is that when I run my application and I try to change everythings, I'm getting the following error.

[image]

I read many thread like:
[Hot Code Replace Failed (eclipse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056628/hot-code-replace-failed-eclipse)
[How do I get Java “hot code replacement” working in JBoss?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538261/how-do-i-get-java-hot-code-replacement-working-in-jboss)

But I'm sure that my jdk is the same for both compile and run steps, I have also the flag Project->Build Automatically activated but each time that I try to modify any thing I get the error above.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Eclipse can't deal very well with hot code modifications.

I would suggest you to have a look to [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/) as I suggest in [Eclipse Hot Code Replace Fail - republish web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610920/eclipse-hot-code-replace-fail-republish-web-application) post.

> JRebel is a JVM Java Agent that integrates with application servers, making classes reloadable with existing class loaders. Only changed classes are recompiled and instantly reloaded in the running application. JRebel plugs into IDEs and build systems.